# No Next.js version could be detected in your project. Make sure `"next"` is installed in "dependencies" or "devDependencies"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, vercel

Im trying to deploy a Next app using vercel cli. I have run `vercel build` and that was completed successfully with no errors - context provided below. I have run the `vercel deploy --prebuilt` command and it was deployed with no errors. When I try to move the project from the preview enviroment to the production environment I error

```
Error: No Next.js version could be detected in your project. Make sure `"next"` is installed in "dependencies" or "devDependencies"
```

this is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "portfolio-website",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@heroicons/react": "^2.0.12",
    "@next/swc-darwin-x64": "^12.3.2",
    "framer-motion": "^7.6.2",
    "next": "^12.2.4",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.38.0",
    "react-simple-typewriter": "^4.0.5",
    "react-social-icons": "^5.15.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "18.11.7",
    "@types/react": "18.0.24",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.8",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.12",
    "eslint": "8.26.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.0.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.18",
    "tailwind-scrollbar": "^2.0.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.1",
    "typescript": "4.8.4"
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "@next/swc-linux-x64-gnu": "12.3.2"
  }
}
```

I also had the error - for the context

```
warn  - Attempted to load @next/swc-darwin-x64, but it was not installed
error - Failed to load SWC binary for darwin/x64, see more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/failed-loading-swc
info  - Creating an optimized production build .Error: Command "npm run build" exited with
```

I had to delete my package.lock.json fill and node_modules and run `npm i @next/swc-darwin-x64`  and `npm i` even tho the dependency at the time was already in my lock file.

I have also tried downgrading my next version but to no avail.

Have tried deploying directly from my git repository but i aslo get the same error

```
[22:29:17.748] Cloning github.com/xxxxx/xxxxxx (Branch: main, Commit: 0fb5a5a)
[22:29:18.540] Cloning completed: 791.508ms
[22:29:19.131] Looking up build cache...
[22:29:19.371] Build Cache not found
[22:29:19.420] Running "vercel build"
[22:29:20.057] Vercel CLI 28.4.12-05a80a4
[22:29:20.485] Installing dependencies...
[22:29:21.273] npm ERR! code EBADPLATFORM
[22:29:21.275] npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for @next/swc-darwin-x64@12.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
[22:29:21.276] npm ERR! notsup Valid OS:    darwin
[22:29:21.276] npm ERR! notsup Valid Arch:  x64
[22:29:21.276] npm ERR! notsup Actual OS:   linux
[22:29:21.276] npm ERR! notsup Actual Arch: x64
[22:29:21.279] 
[22:29:21.279] npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
[22:29:21.279] npm ERR!     /vercel/.npm/_logs/2022-11-02T21_29_20_898Z-debug-0.log
[22:29:21.290] Warning: Could not identify Next.js version, ensure it is defined as a project dependency.
[22:29:21.364] Error: No Next.js version could be detected in your project. Make sure `"next"` is installed in "dependencies" or "devDependencies"
```

Answer (score 6):

I ran into this and solved it by clearing what I had put in the "Root Directory" setting in my vercel config.

I was troubleshooting something else and had set that to "src", which caused this to start showing up. When I set it back to nothing, deployments worked again

Answer (score 1):

I have been getting this error on vercel deployments although I have a next in the dependencies. What I find has been letting me get a good deployment is clearing the cache via

```
git rm -r --cached .
git add --all .
git commit -a -m "Versioning untracked files"
git push origin master
```

When this does not work for me I delete the yarn.lock file and get a good build, maybe a conflict between npm and yarn

Comment: `git push origin main` for newer repositories :)

Answer (score 1):

I am using vercel for my github repo. I had the same problem.

The problem is the file structure. Vercel needs to see your working area with codes and etc. for example

File (github repo folder),
File,
my-app,
.next,
...

This way vercel couldn't see my dependencies inside package.json.

But:

my-app (github repo folder),
.next,
...

I have created a repo again with this file structure. And then it worked. This solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Vercel doesn't support Yarn2 or pnpm, I suspect the problem arises due to Hard Linking of packages

To solve the issues Goto `Build & Development Settings` and Replace `Install Command` with `npm install`

this should solve the issue

and make sure to select appropriate NextJS `Root folder`

Answer (score 0):

First I made sure for the project to be buildable on my environment. Found some missing deps and errors. Once you can build it locally, you can try to deploy it somewhere else and expect it to work.